# How can I make the text of my panel in bold or italic? this is blender python related

Tags: python, interface, customization, panel, font

Basically what I want is to make my panel header in bold and other text in my panel to be italic.
[image: Here is the panel I currently got]

For example: I want the text 'settings' with the preferences icon to be in bold.

This is the code for that example I gave,

`layout.label(text=" ____ Settings",icon = "PREFERENCES")`

Is this possible?

Comment: AFAIK there's no control over that.

Comment: @MartyFouts Ah ok, that's a bit sad that there isn't any way to make a text bold.

Could you upvote this question so that more people can see it? I know that you are highly reputed but still.

Comment: I can and did but I don't think it will help.  It is wise not to believe an answer just because of reputation.  Especially in this case where I'm not certain.  Let's hope someone can help you.

Comment: @MartyFouts lets hope so